# Override a method but leave superclass's calls to that method going to superclass's version of that method

Tags: objective-c, overriding, subclass, superclass

Is it possible to override a method in a subclass in such a way that when the superclass calls the method, those calls still go to the original method, but all other (external) calls to the method go to the overridden version?

*Background*: If I subclass a `UITextField` and override the getter for `delegate`, the built-in behavior of `UITextField` that relies on the delegate appears to be using the backing ivar to access the delegate (and not touching the overridden getter); however, if I try the same thing with `UITextView`, it seems that the internal behavior of `UITextView` that relies on the delegate uses the overridden getter to access the delegate.

Comment: What you said in the first paragraph is how subclassing works. Instances of the subclass use the overridden version of the method; instances of the superclass use the original. Yes, it's possible that `UITextField` interally uses the ivar directly rather than the accessor method for its `delegate`, but it's not at all clear what that has to do with the question in your title and first paragraph. You want the _subclass_ to use your overridden method for any access of the ivar. I'm not sure that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the objc runtime functions

```
#import <objc/message.h>

objc_super superstruct = {self, [UITextField class]};
objc_msgSendSuper(&superstruct, _cmd, args...);
```

Comment: That would let me call the superclass's implementation even when I'd overridden it, right?  I want to make the superclass's calls to the method go to its implementation rather than the overridden one.

Comment: yes. the message dispatch will start from whatever class you specified in the `objc_super` struct

Answer (score 0):

I believe you did something wrong the second time.
You are saying that subclassing UITextView and overriding a method....affects the superclass??
Doesn't sound right at all.
I'd suggest making sure the view you used is an object of the overriden class and not of the default UITextView class.